# How to get all rows from child table when even one child row is updated?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can i get all matching rows from **S_ASSET_XA** (child table) even if one of the child rows is updated/satisfies the condition. Parent table is **S_ASSET**.

Note: **S_ASSET** (parent) and **S_ASSET_XA** (child) has one to many relationship. My requirement is if the parent table is updated, output all the child rows OR if any of the child rows are updated then also output all the child rows. Kindly help.

I tried this, but not working, it's pulling only the updated child row.

```
SELECT
AST.ROW_ID AS ASSET_ID,
AST.ASSET_NUM      AS ASSET_NUM,
XA.ATTR_NAME     AS ATTR_NAME
FROM S_ASSET AST, S_ASSET_XA XA
WHERE AST.ROW_ID = XA.ASSET_ID
AND (AST.LAST_UPD >= TO_DATE('06-JUL-2020 05:01:57','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
OR XA.LAST_UPD  >= TO_DATE('06-JUL-2020 05:01:57','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possibilities, for example `exists` or analytical `max()`:

```
SELECT AST.ROW_ID AS ASSET_ID, AST.ASSET_NUM  AS ASSET_NUM, XA.ATTR_NAME AS ATTR_NAME
FROM S_ASSET AST
join (select asset_id, attr_name, max(last_upd) over (partition by asset_id) max_upd 
        from S_ASSET_XA) XA 
  on AST.ROW_ID = XA.ASSET_ID
  AND greatest(AST.LAST_UPD, XA.max_UPD) >= timestamp '2020-07-06 05:01:57';
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c82ea8782100878083449cb83d37d99)

---

**Edit:** Please check also `exists` version:

```
SELECT AST.ROW_ID AS ASSET_ID, AST.ASSET_NUM  AS ASSET_NUM, XA.ATTR_NAME AS ATTR_NAME
  FROM S_ASSET AST
  join S_ASSET_XA XA on AST.ROW_ID = XA.ASSET_ID
  where AST.LAST_UPD >= timestamp '2020-07-06 05:01:57'
     or exists (select 1 from S_ASSET_XA 
                  where AST.ROW_ID = XA.ASSET_ID 
                    and last_upd >= timestamp '2020-07-06 05:01:57' );
```

and solution with `max()`, where join is made at first and condition last:

```
select ASSET_ID, ASSET_NUM, ATTR_NAME
  from (
    SELECT AST.ROW_ID AS ASSET_ID, AST.ASSET_NUM, XA.ATTR_NAME, ast.last_upd,
           max(xa.last_upd) over (partition by xa.asset_id) max_upd
      FROM S_ASSET AST
      join S_ASSET_XA XA on AST.ROW_ID = XA.ASSET_ID  )
  where greatest(LAST_UPD, max_UPD) >= timestamp '2020-07-06 05:01:57';
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fc130cc1a18d618947115e1525758eda)

Comment: This query provided by Ponder Stibbons is a bit costly performance wise. The partition by clause is taking much time since s_asset_xa is a huge table having around 150+ Million rows. Can anyone please suggest another way which would be lite on performance. Thanks.

Comment: The exists version is much better performance-wise. Thanks for the update.